# Telegram api returns error on join videocall

Tags: java, telegram

I have create telegram client with library https://github.com/tdlight-team/tdlight-java

I'm trying to join just created videoCall:

```
        simpleTelegramClient.send(new TdApi.JoinGroupCall(groupCallID,
                        null,
                        0,
                        "{}",
                        true,
                        false,
                        null),
```

But it returns GROUPCALL_SSRC_DUPLICATE_MUCH. Whate does it mean? and what mean parameters: audioSourceId and payload? Where I could get it? It's about a java wrap around tdlib, but I believe the answer will match with native lib.

Comment: You get the payload from your WebRTC client. You should have an active WebRTC connection alongside that if you want to stay in the call.

Comment: @roj1512 what does WebRTC mean relative to telegram? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data could be received from tgcalls library.

https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/1522